# Google Authentication using django-rest-framework and python-social-auth

Tags: django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

**Question in short**: *Login with DRF, python-social-auth and Angularjs works with Facebook but not Google.*

I'm building a django app that needs to enable users to signup/login via Facebook and Google in addition to locally stored email/password combo. It works as follows:

1. For both signup and login, Angularjs initiates FB and google apis (FB.init and gapi.auth2.init) with their respective app_ids. All js libraries required for this are included in the pages.
2. Based on user's selection, both pages let user to log in using Facebook or google or let them enter their email/password combo.
3. All required info including their `access_token` is collected via FB or Google's API.
4. When user submits the form after filling up all relevant details (signup requires them to enter some additional data), the data including the `access_token` is sent to the server by an AJAX request.
5. At the server side, class based views, LoginView and SignUpView, accepts the requests and processes them. Email-based signup/login is directly handled by the code. Google/FB based signup/login is passed to python-social-auth's `do_auth` function for authentication.
6. When provider chosen is `facebook`, this works fine. When, it's `Google` (Tried both `google-oauth2` and `google-plus`), `do_auth` eventually raises a 403 Forbidden error. When the related url, https://googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&alt=json is copied to the browser, it shows an error message:

> Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires
>   signup

7. I've made sure of the following things:

   1. Enabled Google+ API in the google developer console for the corresponding app
   2. From the google developer console, added `http://localhost:5001` to javascript origin field and `http://localhost:5001/social/complete` to redirect uri field (Latter field is filled up later. Same result with or without it.)
   3. Generated key and copied client_id and client_secret to `settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY` and `settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET`. Double checked their accuracy.
   4. Added `'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2'` to settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS. Tried placing here both GoogleOAuth2 and GooglePlus together and separately.
   5. Tried all these in 2-3 with PLUS also, instead of OAUTH2. Still the same result.
   6. Tried again after setting, `settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_USE_DEPRECATED_API` as True. This also fails but the error is now 401.

What to do next to get this working with Google authentication too? Gone through many other similar questions here and issues reported in Github.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class SignUpView(CreateAPIView):

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        provider = request.data['provider']
        strategy = load_strategy(request)
        backend = load_backend(strategy=strategy, name=provider, redirect_uri=None)
        token = request.data['access_token']
        try:
            user = backend.do_auth(token, user=None, **data)
        except AuthAlreadyAssociated:
            pass
```

Comment: Found this reply of @aragen relevant to my Q: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28355531/7447662. I'm following the same approach as yours. Any idea on this?

Answer (score 5):

I've recently struggled with similar problem, but my situation was a little bit different because I'm using django-rest-framework-social-oauth2.

First of all I've noticed you enabled Google+ API, but:

> Added 'social.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2' to settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS.

Try change your settings to (this is described in [python social auth docs](http://python-social-auth-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/google.html#google-sign-in)) :

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
...
'social_core.backends.google.GooglePlusAuth',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_KEY = '...'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_PLUS_SECRET = '...'
```

Another thing that can be useful for you is [google oauth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/)